# How to unit test componentDidMount using jest/enzyme when Component.prototype returns undefined?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write a simple test to see if the `componentDidMount` gets called in the `HomePage` component below:

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {...}
  async componentDidMount(){
    // a couple of if conditions and an ajax request
  }
}
```

For the test I'm trying the following to see if componentDidMount gets called:

```
describe('<Homepage/>', () => {
  let props, store, mockStore, initialState

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      getPoints: jest.fn(),
      estimatePoints: jest.fn()
    }
    initialState = {
      homeReducer: {
        profile: {}
      },
      pointsReducer: {
        score: {
          points: {}
        }
      }
    }

    mockStore = configureStore()
    store = mockStore(initialState)
  })

  it('should call the componentDidMount lifecycle method', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(HomePage.prototype, 'componentDidMount')
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HomePage {...props}/>
      </Provider>
    )
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    wrapper.unmount()
  })
})
```

The error I'm getting is `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`. I've tried using `shallow` and `wrapper.instance()` as well, both with no luck. What would be the correct way to test the `componentDidMount` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you are using `connect` HOC of `react-redux` wrapped the `HomePage` react component. You need to use [WrappedComponent](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/connect-advanced#static-properties) static property to get the original react component. Then, you can spy on it.

Short answer:

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(HomePage.WrappedComponent.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
```

Completed working example:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {};
  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('a couple of if conditions and an ajax request');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>HomePage</div>;
  }
}

export default connect()(HomePage);
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import HomePage from './';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

describe('<Homepage/>', () => {
  let props, store, mockStore, initialState;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      getPoints: jest.fn(),
      estimatePoints: jest.fn(),
    };
    initialState = {
      homeReducer: {
        profile: {},
      },
      pointsReducer: {
        score: {
          points: {},
        },
      },
    };

    mockStore = configureStore();
    store = mockStore(initialState);
  });

  it('should call the componentDidMount lifecycle method', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(HomePage.WrappedComponent.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HomePage {...props} />
      </Provider>,
    );
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    wrapper.unmount();
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59759511/index.test.tsx (9.85s)
  <Homepage/>
    ✓ should call the componentDidMount lifecycle method (62ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59759511/index.tsx:7
    a couple of if conditions and an ajax request

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.983s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59759511

Comment: fantastic, works like a charm, thanks! Reading up on `wrappedComponent` to better understand why using it works. Any idea why `wrappedComponent` makes it work?

Comment: @complexSandwich Already explain in the answer. Get the unwrapped(original) class-based react component.

Comment: I wish I would have found out this sooner. Thank you :)